# UIImageView not segueing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, segue

I have a `UIImageView` (0x0) in my `NewsTableViewController.swift` which segues to `NewsDetailTableViewController.swift` where the `UIImageView` is 600x216.

If you ask why the first `UIImageView` is 0x0, it is because it is the only way that I know how to segue a different image by each cell. I have 16 cells in my main VC and a different image for each detail VC. I don't want to display the image in the main VC's cell.

If you could suggest another way, that would be great.

Anyway, keeping with this solution, what is the problem with my segue? The images are stored in an array called *`detailImages`*. This array is in `NewsTableViewController.swift`.

Here is my `NewsDetailTableViewController.swift`:

[image]

The `UIImageView` should be where the white space between the title and content is.

Here is my `prepareForSegue` method in my `NewsTableViewController.swift`:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewsDetailTableViewController
            destinationController.item = items[indexPath.row]
            //destinationController.imageNames = detailImages
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `NewsDetailTableViewController.swift` code:

```
import UIKit

class NewsDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var items = [Item]()
var item:Item!
var siteURL = "http://annabellesykes.netau.net/shailenewoodleyfansappjson.json"
var image:UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var segueImageView:UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "News"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    getLatestNews()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsDetailTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.newsDetailTitle.text = item.title
    cell.newsDetailDate.text = item.date
    cell.newsDetailContent.text = item.content
    cell.newsDetailImageView.image = UIImage()

    cell.newsDetailTitle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.newsDetailTitle.numberOfLines = 999
    cell.newsDetailContent.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.newsDetailContent.numberOfLines = 999

    cell.newsDetailTitle.sizeToFit()
    cell.newsDetailContent.sizeToFit()

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func getLatestNews() {

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: siteURL)!)
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if let data = data {
            self.items = self.parseJsonData(data)

            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    })

    task.resume()
}

func parseJsonData(data: NSData) -> [Item] {

    var items = [Item]()

    do {

        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary

        let jsonItems = jsonResult?["items"] as! [AnyObject]
        for jsonItem in jsonItems {
            let item = Item()
            item.title = jsonItem["title"] as! String
            item.content = jsonItem["content"] as! String
            item.date = jsonItem["date"] as! String
            items.append(item)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return items
}


}
```

Here is my `NewsTableViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class NewsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var siteURL = "http://annabellesykes.netau.net/shailenewoodleyfansappjson.json"
var items = [Item]()
var item:Item!
var newsImage:UIImageView?

@IBOutlet weak var imageHeaderView1:UIImageView!

var detailImages = ["newsimage1.jpg", "newsimage2.jpg", "newsimage3.jpg", "newsimage4.jpg", "newsimage5.jpg", "newsimage6.jpg", "newsimage7.jpg", "newsimage8.jpg", "newsimage9.jpg", "newsimage10.jpg", "newsimage10.jpg", "newsimage11.jpg", "newsimage12.jpg", "newsimage13.jpg", "newsimage14.jpg", "newsimage15.jpg", "newsimage16.jpg"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getLatestNews()
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.titleLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].title
    cell.dateLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].date
    cell.contentLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].content
    cell.newsImageView.image = UIImage(named: detailImages[indexPath.row])

    cell.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 999
    cell.contentLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.contentLabel.numberOfLines = 3
    cell.dateLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.dateLabel.numberOfLines = 999

    cell.dateLabel.sizeToFit()

    //cell.imageView?.image = self.imageNames[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction] {

    let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Share", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

        let defaultText = "Check this out: " + self.items[indexPath.row].title + "! " + self.items[indexPath.row].content
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [defaultText], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

    shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 179.0/255.0, green: 239.0/255.0, blue:  247.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    return [shareAction]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    cell.alpha = 0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { cell.alpha = 1 })
}

func getLatestNews() {

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: siteURL)!)
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if let data = data {
            self.items = self.parseJsonData(data)

            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    })

    task.resume()
}

func parseJsonData(data: NSData) -> [Item] {

    var items = [Item]()

    do {

        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary

        let jsonItems = jsonResult?["items"] as! [AnyObject]
        for jsonItem in jsonItems {
            let item = Item()
            item.title = jsonItem["title"] as! String
            item.content = jsonItem["content"] as! String
            item.date = jsonItem["date"] as! String
            items.append(item)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return items
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewsDetailTableViewController
            destinationController.item = items[indexPath.row]
            destinationController.image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: detailImages[indexPath.row]))
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func unwindToHomeScreen(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be setting your image properly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your `NewsDetailTableViewController.swift`.

This line in particular:

`cell.newsDetailImageView.image = UIImage()`

Comment: What shall I do with this line?

Comment: This is where you should set your image, using the content of `detailImages`. But looking at your code it seems like you don't have an array called `detailImages` in `NewsDetailTableViewController.swift`. Where is the image that you want to display stored?

Comment: It's stored in `NewsTableViewController.swift`.

Comment: Ok, my bad. So you have an array of images and you want to pass a specific one to `NewsDetailTableViewController.swift`. I suppose you could create a `UIImage` variable on `NewsDetailTableViewController.swift` and set it in `prepareForSegue`. I assume the value would be `detailImages[indexPath.row]`.

Comment: How would I write this? Like `destinationController.image = UIImage(named: detailImages[indexPath.row])`?

Comment: I did `destinationController.image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: detailImages[indexPath.row]))`, but the image did not show up.

Comment: in `detailImages` do you store the name of the images or the images themselves? If names only, then what you wrote (`destinationController.image = UIImage(named: detailImages[indexPath.row])`) is correct, except you have to make sure that image is a `UIImage` and not `UIImageView`. If you store the images, then you need `destinationController.image = detailImages[indexPath.row]`, here again, make sure image is a `UIImage`. Then replace `cell.newsDetailImageView.image = UIImage()` with `cell.newsDetailImageView.image = image`

Comment: I store the image name in an array, with the images in Xcassets.assets, but `destinationController.image = UIImage(named: detailImages[indexPath.row])` does not show the image in the simulator.

Comment: replace `var image:UIImageView!` with `var image: UIImage?`. And replace `cell.newsDetailImageView.image = UIImage()` with `cell.newsDetailImageView.image = image`. Also, make sure that `detailImages[indexPath.row]` returns an actual image name.

Comment: When I add this, this line in the `prepareForSegue` method comes up with the error 'inout [String]' (aka 'inout Array<String>') is not convertible to 'Array<Element>': `destinationController.image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: detailImages[indexPath.row]))`

Comment: The problem seems to come from elsewhere, could you share more code? I need to see `NewsTableViewController.swift` in particular.

Comment: Okay, I'll add it now.

Comment: replace `destinationController.image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: detailImages[indexPath.row]))` with `destinationController.image = UIImage(named: detailImages[indexPath.row])` and make sure `image` in NewsDetailTableViewController.swift is a UIImage and not UIImageView

Comment: I'll come back to you when my simulator is back up and running, it's having errors at the moment.

Comment: Perfect! It works now! I just want to personally thank you for sticking with me for these days. Most people on this website just leave you, especially newbies and youngsters, so thank you so much, I really appreciate this!

Comment: No problems, glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it solved your issue. Good luck on your app.

Answer (score -2):

```
Here is code in objective c... 
#pragma Mark Prepare For Segue
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue"]) {

    viewcontroller *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.image=[[Apparels objectAtIndex:0];

        }
}

//In other class 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *image;
   UIImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:image];
```

Comment: I use swift, not Obj-C.